# WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission denied in react-native for android devices

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions, permission-denied

When uploading the build on PlayStore for React-Native. It is throwing the error "**Your app currently targets API level 31 and must target at least API level 33 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance**". So I update it to 33. When I open the app, it throws an error "**WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission denied**" alert popup on an Android device.
[image]
Can anyone help me to fix this alert popup issue?

Comment: let deviceVersion = DeviceInfo.getSystemVersion();
let granted = PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.DENIED;
if(deviceVersion >= 13){
granted = PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED;
}else{
granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request( PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE );
}


This above code fixed the issue.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36714